# Ideal page is not shown

Tags: python, django

Ideal page is not shown.
I wrote in views.py

```
def top(request):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    return render(request, 'top.html',{'content':content})

def detail(request,pk):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content':content})
```

in  top.html

```
<div>
         {% for item in content %}
            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <p><a href="{% url 'detail' content.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```

in detail.html

```
<div>
   <h2>{{ content.title }}</h2>
   <p>{{ content.text }}</p>
</div>
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('top/', views.top, name='top'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/',views.detail , name='detail'),
]
```

When I access top method, top.html is shown.And when I click SHOW DETAIL url link, detail.html is shown.But in this detail.html,always content is same.I wanna make a system when I click this link, detail's content is changed each content.pk.But now my system is not my ideal one.Why does my system always return same content in detail.html?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not pulling the object being requested - it's just the same query to pull the list. You need to use `Model.objects.get()` in order to retrieve the detail for the object.

```
def detail(request,pk):
    # Get the object with the matching pk
    content = POST.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content':content})
```

You should also look into [Class Based Views (CBVs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) as what you're doing could be simplified with a `DetailView` and `ListView`.

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but it did not work.detail.html does not show anything.when I print out print(content) in detail method, it does shown only title(I think content has title&text).But I can know content 's value can be gotten.But when I wrote `<h2>{{ content }}</h2>` in detail.html,nothing is shown.How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you try doing `{{content.title}}` like it was before? Also I just realized the link should be `<p><a href="{% url 'detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>` - `item.pk` not `content.pk`.

Comment: When I wrote  `{{content.title}} ` ,in html ` <div>  <!---->  </div>` is shown.So I think values cannot be gotten by using this writing way.I think content.pk is right because when I wrote item.pk,NoReverseMatch error happens.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
def detail(request,pk):
    content = POST.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content':content})
```

You're not doing anything with the primary key (`pk`). You go to the database and fetch the 5 most recent posts. Don't you want it to be:

```
def detail(request,pk):
    content = POST.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'detail.html',{'content':content})
```

?

Since you're doing this for views, I recommend you also take a look to [get_object_or_404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur codes,but it did not work.detail.html does not show anything.when I print out print(content) in detail method, it does shown only title(I think content has title&text).But I can know content 's value can be gotten.But when I wrote `<h2>{{ content }}</h2>` in detail.html,nothing is shown.How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've used the `content` variable instead of `item` in `top.html`, it's always taking `pk` of first element from list. Check below code.

```
<div>
         {% for item in content %}
            <h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>
            <p><a href="{% url 'detail' item.pk %}">SHOW DETAIL</a></p>
         {% endfor %}
</div>
```